# Using Twitter integration (Tweet Sheet) in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios5, twitter, ios-simulator

When I use TWTweetComposeViewController addImage: method to tweet with a image, it always show "Cannot Send Tweet" alert (like following image). But same tweet can be sent on the actual iOS device.

[image: Cannot Send Tweet]

Anyone know what happened?

Code:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

[tweetViewController setInitialText:@"sent from MyTwitterApp"];
[tweetViewController addImage:imageToSave];

[self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
```

***imageToSave** is an UIImage object selected from photo library

Comment: Add code here. Is twitter account added in iPhone settings?

Comment: Yes, Twitter account was already added in iPhone settings.

Comment: Seems that it's not code issue. Try to re-add twitter account in settings.

Comment: I try to delete all Twitter accounts and add them back (many times). But the "Cannot Send Tweet" alert is always showed...

Comment: Did you check that image isn't nil?
            if (image != nil) {
                [twitterController addImage:image];
            }

Comment: Thanks for your reminding again. But I am sure that the image could not be nil, because the Tweet Sheet interface shows there is a image attached.